# Как показать tab bar в модальном окне?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

После клика на "Button" - *Table View* показывается нормально, но пропадает *TabBar*.

Как сделать, чтоб табы показывались?

---

Таб бар в модальном окне:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно выбрать FirstView и вставить Navigation Controller
[image: Emded in NavigationController]

Answer (score 0):

Это логично, что пропадает Tabbar, так как Вы переходе в Detail Controller (в ваше случае table view). Вам нужно добавить Navigation Controller между First View и table view co связью (relationship)"Root" и добавить в навигейшине item назад в First View.